# Webbrowser.open() won't stop opening url in new tab

Tags: python

I'm trying to open a url in Chrome (I am building a flask app).

```py
def some_function():
     url = "https://google.com"
     return webbrowser.open(url,new=0)
```

As you can see it is just a simple function that is opening google.
I did some research and found that you have to set `new` to 0 to open the url in the same tab. But somehow it is still not working. This might be a problem of `chrome` because it's working in safari.

I am kind of frustrated because everywhere I look for a solution it always says that I have to set new to 0...
I hope you can help me.

Comment: Unrelated, but `webbrowser` would use the **local** default browser **of the Flask server**... If you put this in a Flask app and deploy your Flask code to come external server (like, in the cloud), then this wouldn't do what you want as it would not affect the Chrome browser you'd use to view the remote Flask server

Comment: @OneCricketeer I see where ther problem is now. Thank you very much.

Comment: To round it up, what I did is just adding this line to one of my flask routes. `return redirect(url,code=302)`

Comment: Feel free to put that as an answer below